# Set/Delete Cookies on cross subdomain Server Side and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session, cookies, citrix

I have **domain.com**, **sub1.domain.com** and **sub2.domain.com**. From a site of **sub1.domain.com** i call a script to set cookie on **domain.com** like this

```
document.cookie = "KEY=Value; domain=.domain.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:01 GMT";
```

I check browser an see that cookie. Look good. After that I go to **sub2.domain.com** to modify or delete the cookie I've created.

```
document.cookie = "KEY=Deleted; domain=.domain.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:01 GMT";
```

But no luck, Cookies are still there, value remain. What should I do to remove root cookie from subdomain?

EDIT:

To make it clear: I use citrix single sign on to authenticate on both domain. we just have to login to .domain.com and citric will authenticate the rest. But the problem is it does not have sign out mechaniz so I have decide to clear cookies. It work when i clear it with browser plugins. But when it come to code (javascript) it won't work. Does anyone know this

Comment: I foresee 2 possible problems. The 1-st is that you can't actually see this cookie available for `domain.com`, bacause it does not match domain pattern (`.domain.com` can match any `*.domain.com`, including `www.domain.com`, but not `domain.com` without subdomains). So it seems, that first time you checked cookie from either sub1 or sub2, and the second time you checked it from the main domain. The 2-nd possible problem is that you have different sheme (i.e. http and https) or port numbers (it's not clear from the question).

Comment: I check cookies with forefox and I see it... .domain.com is correct. I'm not sure http or https affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I know the problem! Thoese cookie are httponly cookie, that mean we cannot access via javascript. I have to modified them on server side

```
HttpCookie expiredCookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName");
expiredCookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
expiredCookie.Path = "/";
expiredCookie.Domain = ".domain.com";
Response.Cookies.Add(expiredCookie);
```